# Drawing a 3D plot in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

Given an R code, I want to draw a 3D surface plot.

The R code is as follows:

```
x=seq(1,5,1)
y=seq(6,10,1)
m=as.matrix(expand.grid(x,y))
a=m[,1]+m[,2]
mm=cbind(m,a)
mm1=data.frame(aaaa=mm[,1],bbbb=mm[,2],cccc=mm[,3])
```

I want to draw the 3D surface plot, where 'aaaa' will be the 'x' axis, 'bbbb' will be the 'y' axis and 'cccc' will be the 'z' axis.

Comment: the base function for a 3d surface plot is `persp()`. see the documentation (`?persp`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# surface plot
x=seq(1,5,1)
y=seq(6,10,1)
z <- outer(x, y)
nrz <- nrow(z)
ncz <- ncol(z)
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette( c("blue", "green") )
nbcol <- length(a)
color <- jet.colors(nbcol)
zfacet <- z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncz] + z[-nrz, -1] + z[-nrz, -ncz]
facetcol <- cut(zfacet, nbcol)
persp(x, y, z, col = color[facetcol], phi = 30, theta = -30)
```

[image]

or simply this:

```
library(rgl)
persp3d(x,y,z, col=z)
```

[image]